# How to get the full command line in JVMTI?

Tags: java, jvmti

Is it possible to get full command line with all arguments which was used to launch current Java process and to get that during OnLoad phase in JVMTI?

Answer (score 1):

I have consulted the [JVMTI reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jvmti/jvmti.html) and I think that it is not natively provided, I guess your best shot is to use Byte Code Instrumentation (BCI).

Comment: OnLoad happens before any classes are loaded, so it's to early to instrument something.

Comment: You are right, I am afraid that I don't see a possibility. What problem are you trying to solve? Maybe there is a work around, I think about passing the same program arguments to the agent.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to get the pull path but on Oracle JVMs you could use

```
char * res;
jvmti->GetSystemProperty("sun.java.command", &res);
```

to get the main class and arguments.

You can use java.class.path too, so with both you can discover quite a lot about how the command started.